# Tiling of different sized chess boards. Combo Problem

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, tiling

Show that a 444-by-77 chessboard can be completely tiled by 1-by-6 pieces
but a 44-by-777 chessboard cannot.

I tried to show this by taking a multiplication table of both boards and trying to find the area that a tile covers.

This was not the right way to approach this problem. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Since $444$ is a multiple of $6$, it’s easy to tile the $444\times 77$ board. Color the $44\times 777$ board diagonally with $6$ colors, like this:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&1&2&3&\ldots\\ \hline
2&3&4&5&6&1&2&3&4&\ldots\\ \hline
3&4&5&6&1&2&3&4&5&\ldots\\ \hline
4&5&6&1&2&3&4&5&6&\ldots\\ \hline
5&6&1&2&3&4&5&6&1&\ldots\\ \hline
6&1&2&3&4&5&6&1&2&\ldots\\ \hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&1&2&3&\ldots\\ \hline
2&3&4&5&6&1&2&3&4&\ldots\\ \hline
3&4&5&6&1&2&3&4&5&\ldots\\ \hline
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Each tile must cover exactly one square of each color. Show that this is impossible, because there are not the same numbers of squares of each color.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint! I see what I need to do on this problem now

Comment: @Dylan: You’re very welcome.